# Counting, highlighting and printing the duplicates between two arrays

Tags: php, arrays

First time posting on stackoverflow.

After printing the main array, I have managed to highlight the values that are found in the second one, but I also want to print the number of times that the duplicate occurs in brackets at the same time. I have run out of the ideas on how to do that last part, I get stuck in multiple loops and other problems. I will paste here what's working for now.

The code:

```
$main = array( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
               12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 );

$secondary = array( 1, 6, 10, 6, 17, 6, 17, 20 );

foreach ( $main as $number )

{

if ( in_array( $number, $secondary ) ) 

{

echo $item;

// this one is supposed to be highlighted, but the html code disappears on stackoverflow

/* this is where the number of duplicates should appear in bracket, example: 

highlighted number( number of duplicates ) */

 }

else

{

echo $item;

// this one is simple

}
}
```

EXPECTED RESULT:

1(1), 2, 3, 4, 5, 6(3), 7, 8, 9, 10(1), 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17(2), 18, 19, 20(1)

Basically the brackets contain the number of times that the value is found in the second array, aside from being colored, but I can't paste the html code for some reason. Sorry for not making the expected result more clear !

PROBLEM SOLVED:
Thanks to everyone for your help, first time using this website, didn't expect such a quick response from you guys. Thank you very much !

Comment: Can you please post your expected result..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the count values of your `secondary` array first using [array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php). This is what you can acquire as

```
$main = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20);

$secondary = array(1, 6, 10, 6, 17, 6, 17, 20);
$count_values = array_count_values($secondary);

foreach ($main as $key => $value) {
    if (in_array($value, $secondary)) {
        echo $value . "<strong>(" . $count_values[$value] . ")</strong>";
        echo ( ++$key == count($main)) ? '' : ',';
    } else {
        echo $value;
        echo ( ++$key == count($main)) ? '' : ',';
    }
}
```

Output:

1(1),2,3,4,5,6(3),7,8,9,10(1),11,12,13,14,15,16,17(2),18,19,20(1)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $secondary is the one with the dupes, you should go about it the other way:

```
$dupes = array();
foreach($secondary as $number) {
   if (in_array($number, $main)) {
      $dupes[$number]++;
   }
}
var_dump($dupes);
```

Comment: This is not what I am looking for, but thank you for your help. I will edit my original post with an expected result.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <?php
    $main = array( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,18,19,20);
    $secondary = array( 1, 6, 10, 6, 17, 6, 17, 20 );
    $result =array();
    foreach($main as $key => $value){
        $i=0;
        foreach($secondary as $key1 => $value1){
            if($value == $value1){
                $i++;
            }
            $result[$value] = $i;
       }
    }
     $resultString  ='';
    foreach($result as $key => $value){
     $resultString .=$key.'('.$value.'),' ;
    }
   echo trim($resultString,',');
    ?>
```

Result:

```
1(1),2(0),3(0),4(0),5(0),6(3),7(0),8(0),9(0),10(1),11(0),12(0),13(0),14(0),15(0),16(0),17(2),18(0),19(0),20(1)
```